# jenkins two pipielines with one build step

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build two services which are using same docker image with different environment variable.
To achieve this, I'm going to create two jenkins pipelines which consist of "build -> deploy".
Functionally it's working well but I'd like to above building same image twice. As suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: you can use two build stage in one pipeline, each stage you can specify the diff env by docker build option `--env "<env_name>=<env_value>"`. Please use diff image tag.